# How to calculate number of strings in a DataFrame

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe, count

I am trying to count the number of strings in a column of my dataframe.

```py
>>> import pandas as pd                                                              

>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['a','b','c',1,2,3],
                       'B':['pp','qq','rr',3,4,5]})
>>> df
   A   B
0  a  pp
1  b  qq
2  c  rr
3  1   3
4  2   4
5  3   5

>>> df['A'].str.count('/w')                                                          
0    0.0
1    0.0
2    0.0
3    NaN
4    NaN
5    NaN
Name: A, dtype: float64
```

What should I do instead of `df['A'].str.count('/w')`?

Comment: So, what is the expected count for this dataframe?

Comment: `df.A.str.count('[a-zA-Z]+').sum()`?

Comment: `df.A.contains('\w+').sum()`?

Comment: `df.apply(lambda x:x.str.contains('\w+').sum())` for whole dataframe over each column. Total number of strings is `df.apply(lambda x:x.str.contains('\w+').sum()).sum()`-->6

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
df['B'].str.count(r'\w+').sum()
```

Output

```
3.0
```

Answer (score 1):

**For your problem:**

List compression should solve your problem.

```
x = len([x for x in list(df["A"]) if type(x) == str])
```

**Output** : 3

**To count a specific instance:**

I think `df.column_name.value_counts()[char]`where `df` is the name of the datframe `column_name` is the name of the column under consideration and `char` is the character or the number or the string you are looking for.

Do `df.A.value_counts()["a"]` to count the number of `a` character in column `A` of `df` dataframe.

For numbers you can do `df.A.value_counts()[1]` to count the number of 1s in `A` column of `df`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to count the number of strings in all the cells of the dataframe irrespective of the column, try this:

```
# convert all the cells of the df into a single list
ls = df.values.tolist()
ls = [item for sublist in ls for item in sublist]

count = 0

for val in ls:
    if isinstance(val, str):
        count += 1

print(count)
```

Output:

```
6
```